# Craft install failed on WAMP

Tags: install

I carefully read the installation manual, read PHP and apache error logs, but I still don't know why it's failed.
(**Solution - Maximum execution time of 120 seconds is not enough**)
 - Windows 10 64
 - WAMP 3.1.7 64
 - Craft 3.0.37
 - PHP 7.2.14 with all ext
 - MySQL 5.7.24

What I've done to install:

1) download Craft zip from official site
2) create folder for Craft site in "www" directory in WAMP folder
3) unpack Craft zip in that folder
4) create virtual host with directory: `www/craft/web` through WAMP virtualHost manager
5) uncheck "read-only" box for .env, composer.json, composer.lock, config/license.key, storage/*, vendor/*, web/cpresources/*
6) manually set security key in .env
7) create database with utf8 unicode general ci
8) open http://myHostName/index.php?p=admin/install in browser
9) take steps in wizzard and start installation procces
10) after a minute recieve this page
[image: error massage screenshot]

11) Check WAMP apache-error, php-error, mysql logs and found no records
12) check acces.log

> ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:41:50 +0300] "GET /index.php?p=admin/install HTTP/1.1" 200 134469
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:41:52 +0300] "GET /cpresources/49ee4f09/css/craft.css?v=1548609540 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:41:52 +0300] "GET /cpresources/79140749/selectize.css?v=1548609540 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:41:52 +0300] "GET /cpresources/49ee4f09/css/charts.css?v=1548609540 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:41:52 +0300] "GET /cpresources/5f5e13e4/install.css?v=1548609540 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:41:52 +0300] "GET /cpresources/19922aaf/d3.js?v=1548609540 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:41:52 +0300] "GET /cpresources/da22e3a5/element-resize-detector.js?v=1548609540 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:41:52 +0300] "GET /cpresources/2b68d36c/jquery.js?v=1548609540 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:41:52 +0300] "GET /cpresources/45bbaf3c/jquery.mobile-events.min.js?v=1548609540 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:41:52 +0300] "GET /cpresources/f7ebee0a/velocity.js?v=1548609540 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:41:53 +0300] "GET /cpresources/10721d1a/garnish.js?v=1548609540 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:41:53 +0300] "GET /cpresources/fee67a92/jquery-ui.min.js?v=1548609540 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:41:53 +0300] "GET /cpresources/7e624b4f/datepicker-ru.js?v=1548609540 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:41:53 +0300] "GET /cpresources/8f12d058/picturefill.js?v=1548609540 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:41:53 +0300] "GET /cpresources/3fd53370/jquery.payment.js?v=1548609540 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:41:53 +0300] "GET /cpresources/79140749/selectize.js?v=1548609540 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:41:53 +0300] "GET /cpresources/6dadc32d/jquery.fileupload.js?v=1548609540 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:41:53 +0300] "GET /cpresources/221c0e10/xregexp-all.js?v=1548609540 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:41:53 +0300] "GET /cpresources/f8dd2f28/fabric.js?v=1548609540 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:41:53 +0300] "GET /cpresources/49ee4f09/js/Craft.min.js?v=1548609540 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:41:53 +0300] "GET /cpresources/5f5e13e4/install.min.js?v=1548609540 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:41:53 +0300] "GET /cpresources/5f5e13e4/images/install-bg-1920.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:41:54 +0300] "GET /cpresources/49ee4f09/images/spinner_big.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:41:57 +0300] "GET /cpresources/49ee4f09/fonts/Craft.woff HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:42:03 +0300] "GET /cpresources/5f5e13e4/images/spinner_submit.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:42:03 +0300] "POST /index.php?p=admin/actions/install/validate-account HTTP/1.1" 200 30
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:44:39 +0300] "POST /index.php?p=admin/actions/install/validate-site HTTP/1.1" 200 30
>   ::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:44:39 +0300] "POST /index.php?p=admin/actions/install/install HTTP/1.1" 500 598

Database screenshot
[image]

What do I need to read or to do with this to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to the Craft CMS Stack Exchange, Artur! Could you please add more information that might help people here provide answers? For example, the Craft CMS version, what you've done to install, and exactly what the failure looks like (error messages, output, blank page, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for fast response. I update information in my question

Comment: Is your database seems to have rightly created by the installer ? (Do you see some craft' tables?)

Comment: Yes, some about 60 empty tables, i add screenshot of it

Comment: I think the important part of those logs are the last bit, which show a 500 Internal Server Error: `::1 - - [28/Jan/2019:12:44:39 +0300] "POST /index.php?p=admin/actions/install/install HTTP/1.1" 500 598`

Comment: My guess is the underlying error message will be in the Craft log files in Craft's `storage/logs` folder.

Comment: Brad Bell, you right, it was so easy!
[29-Jan-2019 07:56:12 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in. 

But in admin panel i have another error's, but main problem is solved. Thank you